# Can a MSP430 be programmed with only VDD/RST/TST/GND connectors?

Tags: msp430

I've inherited a bit of a project and I need help. I have a PCB with only VDD/RST/TST/GND connectors and a MSP430-G2402 controller on the other side. I need to reprogram the microcontroller. I ideally need to actually pull the code off, modify it, and then put the new code back onto it. I was thinking about buying one of these off of ebay: MSP430 USB Debug Interface Emulator MSP-FET430UIF and attempting to solder connections to this device. Is this even possible? and if so how would I go about wiring the two together? It doesn't appear there is a VDD wire on the MSP-FET USB Programming device. I would assume I would wire RST/TST/GRND all to the existing wires on the FET.

If someone could please get me started in the right direction. I have already reviewed all the manuals for these devices and was unable to find a very good answer.

Comment: As far as I know, NO you cannot program with only VDD/RST/TST/GND. You do need JTAG or SWD link to program/debug the microcontroller.

Comment: Looks like these are sufficient for the "Spy-bi-wire" interface, which can be used to program it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be possible. You can read the features with TI's debugger/emulator/programmer
documentation
https://www.ti.com/tool/MSP-FET

[image]
This is the minimal 2 wire JTAG interface. The documentation also describes the 4 wire interface.

Answer (score 0):

The MSP430 Family supports a 4-wire and 2-wire Spy-Bi-Wire interface.

For 2-wire Spy-Bi-Wire you need to connect the signals as follows:
[image]

Source: [TI Forum](https://e2e.ti.com/support/microcontrollers/msp-low-power-microcontrollers-group/msp430/f/msp-low-power-microcontroller-forum/303018/spy-bi-wire-and-jtag-interfacing)

---

[Tony's answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/627903/301846) is the correct one that should be accepted.

Mine is the minimal approach if the JTAG fuse blow functionality isn't needed, as seen in the foot notes on [page 22](https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/slau278ah/slau278ah.pdf?ts=1658122720070).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the fine answer by @TonyStewart, you should note that you do not need to limit yourself to the UIF version of the MSP-FET.  You can make similar connections to the current MSP-Fet programmer as well.  I use this setup routinely.
[image]

[image]

Good luck!

-Chris

Answer (score 0):

The g2402 supports SPi-Bi-Wire SBW programming. It uses a smaller section of the jtag pins for a 2 pin jtag interface (plus power).

[image]

https://www.ti.com/product/MSP430G2402

You'd be better off with a MSP-EXP430G2 or MSP-EXP430G2ET Launchpad development board with its on board SBW interface. It's cheaper, brand new out the box, and you get some extra microcontrollers. Plus it has a 3.6V VCC pin you can use as well. It's designed for both on board and off board programming.

https://www.ti.com/tool/MSP-EXP430G2ET

### Side note

***You're not going to get readble code off it.*** Your only going to get machine code or generic assembly code at best. All the commented human readable code is lost when programmed to the IC. So yeah you could pull the code off, and program it again. But modifying the code won't be straight forward. You'll need to look into an IDA with msp430 support in order to try to reverse engineer the code.